# Compare two strings and match it cases

Tags: javascript, canvas, captcha

I am trying to create a captcha on the client side using canvas, what I want is to match the two strings and compare it, for example the generated captcha output is

**1Gh3Ry** I want to match it based on the users input to match the captcha, so if the user inputs 1gH3ry it would be wrong.

Is there a way to do it using Regular expressions?

Thank you.

This is my captcha code.

```
 var tCtx = document.getElementById("textCanvas").getContext("2d");
  var imageElem = document.getElementById("image");
  var result = "";

  function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
  }

  var newElem = makeid();
  tCtx.font = "italic 22pt deportee";
  tCtx.fillStyle = "#333333";
  tCtx.textAlign = 'left';
  tCtx.fillText(newElem, 10, 30);
  imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Why would you need regular expression to compare two strings? O.o  `if (captchaCode === userInput) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Yeah, it is not a good approach to use regex for simple string manipulations like equal cases.

Comment: sometimes I am a freaking idiot. I think that I need regular expression but === works. Thank you Andreas.